# displaying min/max inputs in python. getting TypeError:'int"

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm taking an intro to python class and I am having issues with my code displaying the min/max of inputted values.  when I go to run the program it gives me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterabl

This program will allow the user to enter an integer values until 0 is entered The progam will display the lagest and smallest number entered.

```
value = int(input('What is your value? '))

maxNumber = 0
minNumber = 0

while(value != 0):
    if(value > 0):
        maxNumber = max(value)
    else:
        minNumber = min(value)

    value = int(input('What is the next value? '))


print(maxNumber)
print(minNumber)
```

main()

Comment: What do you imagine that `min(1)` would return`?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: What do you think ``minNumber`` should be if the user inputs 1, 10 and 5?

Comment: thank you everyone. I'll give these a try when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

max and min take a series of arguments and return the largest/smallest of them. I think you meant to take the maximum(minimum) between the new value and the current maximum(minimum):

```
if (value > 0):
    maxNumber = max(maxNumber, value)
    # Here ---------^
else:
    minNumber = min(minNumber, value)
    # And here -----^
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow. When you ask for `input()`, you are asking for a string input from the user. This is then turned into an `int` object through the `int()` method. You can't iterate through an `int` object, but you can iterate through lists, tuples, and dicts. What you should do is take user input in a loop and exit, or `break`, the loop when the user enters 0. Here's some code:

```
values = []  # A list of values that will store the inputs.
while True:  # A loop that will indefinitely run.
    value = int(input("Enter a number"))
    if value == 0:
        break
```

Another way of doing this is:

```
values = []  # A list of values that will store the inputs. 
value = None  # A placeholder for inputs that will be used within the loop.
while value != 0:  # Checks if the last input was 0 every iteration.
    value = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

All you would have to do at the end would be to use the `min()` and `max()` methods, which return minimum and maximum values from an iterable object.

```
maxNumber = max(values)
minNumber = min(values)
print(maxNumber)
print(minNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

max and min returns the maximum/minimum of an iterable or multiple values passed to them. One quick way to fix your code is:

```
maxnumber = max(value, maxnumber)

minnumber = min(value, minnumber)
```

Comment: also as you have initialized your minnumber to 0 so unless you provide a negative number e.g. -7 the min number will come as 0